# How to convert TSQL Datetime to Julian INT date

Tags: t-sql

I would like know how to convert date in sql to julian date int,

eg.

if my date was "01 Mar 2011" how do I convert this to Julian date (734197)?

Answer (score 1):

```
declare @d datetime = '20110301'
select datediff(d, 0, @d) + 693596
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 DECLARE @normal_date VARCHAR(30)='2024/3/30';

 SELECT @normal_date AS NormalDate,CONVERT(varchar,(CONVERT(INT,
 SUBSTRING(@normal_date,1,2))%20)+1)+ CONVERT(varchar,
 SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar,( datepart(year, @normal_date) * 1000 + 
 datepart(dy, @normal_date))), 3, 5)) AS JulianDate;
```